# Change in Bitnami Wordpress AWS Public IP

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

Public IP of my wordpress website hosted on AWS got changed.
After getting the new Public IP i update the wp_options table for site_url and also wp_configs.php

But the url of my static content is like:

```
http://52.36.13.144/52.36.13.144/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/deepika.jpg
```

The host ip is getting appended twice. I am not able to figure out why?

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami stacks automatically update the configuration during boot up when there has been a change of IP address.

The issue you describe can happen if the value of `WP_SITEURL` or `WP_HOME` in the `wp_configs.php` file doesn't include the `http://` prefix. Instead of setting the IP address manually, you may define them as follows:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

With those setting in place, you may set the value of the options `siteurl` and `home` in the `wp_options` table of the site database to `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/`.